# Jenkins/groovy CPS issue : artifactoryUpload

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cps

I'm getting same issue listed as fixed here : https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58643

We are using Jenkins 2.190.3.2

```
     stage('upload artefactory') {
        steps {
                sh "touch /tmp/blabla"
                sh "gzip /tmp/blabla"
            script {
                server = Artifactory.server('myid')
                server.credentialsId = 'my-cred'
                def uploadSpec = """{
                  "files": [
                    {
                      "pattern": "/tmp/blabla.gz",
                      "target": "pkg/com/myentreprise/mystuff/scm/dumps/solr/"
                    }
                 ]
                }"""
                server.upload spec: uploadSpec, failNoOp: true
            }
        }
    }
```

[Pipeline] artifactoryUpload
expected to call org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.ArtifactoryServer.upload but wound up catching artifactoryUpload; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed in Pipeline Groovy 2.75

We have 2.74, thus why we still ahve this bug.

Only solution seems to be to upgrade.